# Properties of mollification

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

We have this theorem

For any $1\le p<\infty$ and
$f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$, then $\|f*\phi_\delta - f\|_p\to 0$ as
$\delta\to0$, where $\phi$ is any nonnegative measurable function on
$\mathbb{R}^k$ with total integral one.

and the proof:

We need to prove that
$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\|f*\phi_\delta-f\|_p=0.$$

we have
$$|(f*\phi_\delta)(x)-f(x)|\le
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}|f(x-y)-f(x)|\phi_\delta(y)\,dm(y).$$ Since
$\phi_\delta$ is a positive function with integral one, we may apply
Jensen's Inequality for the convex function $t\mapsto t^p$ to find
\begin{eqnarray*}
|(f*\phi_\delta)(x)-f(x)|^p &\le& \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} |f(x-y)-f(x)|\phi_\delta
(y)\,dm(y)\right)^p \\
&\le& \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} |f(x-y)-f(x)|^p\phi_\delta
(y)\,dm(y).
\end{eqnarray*} 
Now we may integrate this inequality over $\mathbb{R}^k$ in
$x$ and use Fubini's Theorem to find
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|f*\phi_\delta-f\|_p^p &\le&\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}|f(x-y)-f(x)|^p
\phi_\delta(y)\,dm(y)\,dm(x) \\
&=& \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}|f(x-y)-f(x)|^p\,dm(x)\,
\phi_\delta(y)\,dm(y) \\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \|f^y-f\|_p^p\,\phi_\delta(y)\,dm(y).
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $g(y)=\|f^y-f\|_p^p$.  $g$
is a continuous function, and it is clear that $g(0)=0$. Moreover,
$g$ is bounded since
$$g(y)=\|f^y-f\|_p^p \le(\|f^y\|_p + \|f\|_p)^p = (2\|f\|_p)^p.$$ We
continue computing to find
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\|f*\phi_\delta-f\|_p^p &\le& \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(y)\phi_\delta(y)\,dm(y) \\
&=& \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(y)\delta^{-k}\phi(y\delta^{-1})\,dm(y), \\
&=& \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(\delta s)\phi(s)\,dm(s)
\end{eqnarray*}
for the change of variables $s=y\delta^{-1}$. As $\delta\to0$,
$g(\delta s)\phi(s)\to g(0)\phi(s)=0$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^k$.
Moreover, the integrand $g(\delta s)\phi(s)\le \|g\|_\infty \phi(s)$
for all $\delta$. Since $g$ is bounded and $\phi$ is integrable, the
Dominated Convergence Theorem applies to show that
$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} g(\delta s)\phi(s)\,dm(s)=0.$$ This
implies $\|f*\phi_\delta-f\|_p\to0$ as $\delta\to0$.

---

My problem is that I do not understand how it applies the Dominated Convergence Theorem at the end of the proof. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What don't you understand exactly? The assumptions of the dominated convergence are checked.

Comment: In dominated convergence theorem we have that $n\rightarrow\infty$, but now $\delta\rightarrow 0$

Comment: You can use the classical dominated convergence theorem for each sequence $(\delta_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ going to $0$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Can you tell me a book to read this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we need is the following: if $(f_\delta)_{\delta\in (0,1]}$ is a family of function indexed by a real number $\delta$ such that the function 
$t\mapsto \sup_{\delta\in(0,1]}\left|f_\delta(t)\right|$ is integrable and for each $t$, $\lim_{\delta\to 0}f_\delta(t)=0$, then $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R}f_\delta(t)\mathrm d\lambda(t)=0$.

To prove this, assume that $\int_{\mathbb R}f_\delta(t)\mathrm d\lambda(t)$ does not converge to $0$ as $\delta$ goes to $0$. This means that there exists some positive $\varepsilon$ and a sequence $\left(\delta_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ which converges to $0$ such that for each $n$, 
$$\tag{*}\left|\int_{\mathbb R}f_{\delta_n}(t)\mathrm d\lambda(t)\right|\gt \varepsilon.$$
Now, the sequence $\left(f_{\delta_n}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ satisfies the assumptions of the classical dominated convergence theorem, hence (*) entails a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I understood that. I don't understand that in the theorem of Lebesgue we have the condition that $n\rightarrow\infty$ . Now I have that the $\delta\rightarrow 0$. 
It is correct to say that because we change variables $s=y\delta^{-1}$, when $\delta\rightarrow 0$ we have that $s\rightarrow\infty$? And s plays the rore of n?

Comment: No, we pick a sequence $(\delta_n)$ which converges to $0$.  Hence this is "the converges $n\to +\infty$" with $f_{\delta_n}$.

Comment: Can you apply the theorem more analytic?